How do I get the theme color in python-pptx?
Simply put, I want to get an RGB value from a ColorFormat object, ie presentation.slides[0].shapes[0].text_frame.paragraphs.runs[0].color.
If color.type == MSO_COLOR_TYPE.SCHEME then it means the color is based off one of the slide deck's preset color schemes.
Attempting to do color.rgb yields

AttributeError: no .rgb property on color type '_SchemeColor'

I want to get the RGB for a ColorFormat of type SCHEME.

Per the author, the library does not support much in the way of themes so the solution I found is to parse the XML manually.
from pptx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE as RT
from pptx.oxml import parse_xml

from lxml import etree
def get_theme_colors(presentation):
    theme_part = presentation.slide_master.part.part_related_by(RT.THEME)
    theme = parse_xml(theme_part.blob)
    color_elements = theme.xpath('a:themeElements/a:clrScheme/*')
    result = {}
    for element in color_elements:
        namespaces = {'a': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main'}
        root = etree.fromstring(etree.tostring(element))
        theme_name = element.tag.replace('{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main}', '')
        result[theme_name] = root.xpath('//a:srgbClr/@val', namespaces=namespaces)[0]
    return result

This yields a dictionary that maps the scheme name to the RGB which can be looked up
{'dk1': '8B2A0E', 'lt1': '8B2A0E', 'dk2': 'A7A7A7', 'lt2': '535353', 'accent1': '1E2D31', 'accent2': '273C42', 'accent3': '83D061', 'accent4': 'F6CD4C', 'accent5': 'AF4345', 'accent6': 'F58F8F', 'hlink': '0000FF', 'folHlink': 'FF00FF'}

Unfortunately the identifiers don't match up 1:1 so you'll have to do some massaging of the scheme names to get the lookup to work with your specific slide.
